# Using HSQLDB in the embedded mode

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, desktop-application, hsqldb

I'm currently developing a java desktop application using netbeans + hibernate + hsqldb in embedded mode.

While creating a new database I got this exception: `Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost using org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect)`

[image]

Comment: Why are you running in the embedded mode?

Comment: I guess... the Driver Name should be HSQLDB(Server)

Comment: I want that the database be part of my application

Comment: Have u included the appropriate jar files in ur classpath?

Comment: @codeMan it is the same problem

Comment: @codeMan yes I have added the hsqldb.jar to my classpath

Comment: take a look at this : http://wiki.netbeans.org/HSQLDBenNetBeans is that how u r setting up?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36317/discussion-between-codeman-and-nawara)

Answer (score 7):

The URL `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost` is for access to an HSQLDB server running on the local machine. If you want to use HSQLDB this way, your application must start this server before connecting to it. The client/server method of access is actually a good idea for developing the application, because you can access the server from outside your app at the same time.

For development, you can start the server outside your app from the command line. The server can keep running when you restart the app.

The URL for an embedded mode database with files is `jdbc:hsqldb:file:<your file path>` and is documented in the HSQLDB Guide.

http://hsqldb.org/doc/

Comment: yes and the file in the embedded mode should respect the hsqldb architecture 
what is better for a swing app server/embedded mode ?

Comment: What URL should be used if the property in Java app is `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb`?

Comment: `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb` itself is a URL for memory-only databases.